# ServiceBuilder not creating FinderImpl class?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-service-builder

I create some services using Liferay 7 . But **FinderImpl** and **FinderUtil** classes are not created after building services.The steps I followed are as follows:

1. Created a service builder project.
2. Created finder columns.
3. Built and deployed the *-api and *-service...where * is the project/service name.
4. Refresh the project using gradle ->Refresh Gradle Project.
5. Dragged and dropped the *-service and *-api onto the running server.

**Result**: it creates the table but *FinderImpl and *FinderUtil classes are not there in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your `*FinderImpl` class and rebuild service because Finder classes are not created by default. According to the Liferay documentation:

> The first step is to create a `*FinderImpl` class in the service persistence package. For the Guestbook application, for example, you could create a `EntryFinderImpl` class in the `com.liferay.docs.guestbook.service.persistence.impl` package. Your class should extend `BasePersistenceImpl<Entry>`.
>
> Run Service Builder to generate the `*Finder` interface and the `*Util` class for the finder. Service Builder generates the `*Finder` interface and the `*FinderUtil` utility class based on the `*FinderImpl` class. Modify your `*FinderImpl` class to have it implement the `*Finder` interface you just generated:

Source: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/custom-sql

Comment: Finder interface has been created.I implemented that interface but FinderUtil class not been created!!

Comment: You have to re-run `gradlew buldService` to generate the FinderUtil classes.